# Fail to run word embedding example in tensorflow tutorial with GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run the word embedding example code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/word2vec (installed with GPU version of tensorflow under Ubuntu 14.04), but it returns the following error message:

```
Found and verified text8.zip
Data size 17005207
Most common words (+UNK) [['UNK', 418391], ('the', 1061396), ('of', 593677), ('and', 416629), ('one', 411764)]
Sample data [5239, 3084, 12, 6, 195, 2, 3137, 46, 59, 156]
3084 -> 12
originated -> as
3084 -> 5239
originated -> anarchism
12 -> 3084
as -> originated
12 -> 6
as -> a
6 -> 12
a -> as
6 -> 195
a -> term
195 -> 6
term -> a
195 -> 2
term -> of
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 12
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:88] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.076
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 12.00GiB
Free memory: 443.32MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:88] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.076
pciBusID 0000:05:00.0
Total memory: 12.00GiB
Free memory: 451.61MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:112] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:122] 0:   Y Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:122] 1:   Y Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:643] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:643] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_region_allocator.cc:47] Setting region size to 254881792
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_region_allocator.cc:47] Setting region size to 263835648
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 12
Initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word2vec_basic.py", line 171, in <module>
    _, loss_val = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 345, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 419, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'GradientDescent/update_Variable_2/ScatterSub': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '' because the node was colocated with a group of nodes that required incompatible device '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/GPU:0'
     [[Node: GradientDescent/update_Variable_2/ScatterSub = ScatterSub[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64, use_locking=false](Variable_2, gradients/concat_1, GradientDescent/update_Variable_2/mul)]]
Caused by op u'GradientDescent/update_Variable_2/ScatterSub', defined at:
  File "word2vec_basic.py", line 145, in <module>
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 167, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 256, in apply_gradients
    update_ops.append(self._apply_sparse(grad, var))
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent.py", line 40, in _apply_sparse
    return var.scatter_sub(delta, use_locking=self._use_locking)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 324, in scatter_sub
    use_locking=use_locking)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 227, in scatter_sub
    name=name)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 633, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1710, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/chentingpc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 988, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

When I run the code in CPU version tensorflow, it works just fine. But not for GPU version. I also tried to use tf.device('/cpu:0') to force it using CUP instead of GPU, but it produces the same output.

Is there any function in this example cannot be run in GPUs? And how do I switch to CPU without reinstalling CPU version of tensorflow since tf.device('/cpu:0') not working?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems a whole bunch of operations used in this example aren't supported on a GPU. A quick workaround is to restrict operations such that only matrix muls are ran on the GPU.

There's an example in the docs: http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework.md

See the section on tf.Graph.device(device_name_or_function)

I was able to get it working with the following:

```
def device_for_node(n):
  if n.type == "MatMul":
    return "/gpu:0"
  else:
    return "/cpu:0"

with graph.as_default():
  with graph.device(device_for_node):
    ...
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! Another question is can I use multiple CPUs/threads for training in this example? Even if I specify it using CPUs, the logging information still not showing any info. about the CPUs/threads that used?

Answer (score 4):

- scatter_sub is only supported on cpu in the current release.
- I expect that adding on Ln119: with tf.device("/cpu:0") should force everything to use cpus. How did you use tf.device?

Comment: Yes, it works to add tf.device in Ln119, I originally added it to Ln159 in the beginning of session. But even I forced it using cpus, it still didn't show cpu information, and how many cpus cores/threads can it use?

Comment: local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 12
local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 12  shows TF detects that you have 12 cpus'' and it can leverage these much concurrency (loosely speaking). The actual concurrency available depends on the TF program setup. You can tell TF to use X number of threads via SessionOptions. Also, if you run word2vec_optimized, you should expect to see all CPUs are busy.

Comment: So with the basic version, it has used as much threads it can (which was about three or four threads I can recall)? In order to utilize more CPU parallelism, there is no automatic way but have to hand craft it right?

Comment: Update: `scatter_sub` works on GPU now: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/scatter_op_gpu.cu.cc